# What is the rationale behind Spring Security using MD5 for hashing the OAuth and Refresh tokens before storing them in the datastore?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

While MD5 is no longer a recommended cryptography option for hashing (from what I learned), what is the rationale behind Spring Security implementing it to hash the OAuth and Refresh tokens before storing them to data store? Static code analysis tools run against our code base have raised usage of MD5 as PCI non-compliance. What could be the justification to ignore this if I have to? Is Spring planning to roll out an update with a different hashing algorithm? Our refresh tokens are set to live for a day and OAuth tokens for 30 minutes, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is not being used here for any cryptographic properties, just as a way to generate a unique key (and unless you are minting more tokens than there are atoms in the universe I doubt it will cause problems).

Comment: Thanks Dave, for your answer. But the OAuth and refresh tokens generated by Spring (which is GUID) is equally unique as the output of MD5, because both are 128 bit values. So, why would a GUID token need be hashed using MD5 to produce a different value (which is not going to be any more unique)?

Comment: Also, if MD5 is not used for it's cryptographic properties, why is the token returned to a consumer the pre-image value; while what's stored in the database is an MD5 hashed value?

Comment: I believe it is stored in the database in both forms. The hash is used as a primary key, and it is a hash over all the information in the authentication (could be a lot more than just a UUID).